# How to download Slack history messages if you are not the app admin?

Tags: access-token, slack, msr

I am trying to download the history messages for a specific Slack app, let's say [MLflow](https://mlflow-users.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtMzkxMTAwNTcyODM5LTNkNTc5YWZlNDNjMzZiYWJhOTQwMjYwYWE3NDU2YTgzMDViYjJhNWI1MGI4NjViNTA0M2FhMzNhZTVkODE2NmU).

I found a few open-source tools on Github but none of them actually work for me. It seems that slack has disabled ways for non-admin to create the access token since May 2020. Is there any way for the scraping script to work without tokens? WHat else can I do now?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the app called [Backupery for Slack](https://www.backupery.com/products/backupery-for-slack/)

**Disclaimer:** I'm the developer of the app and the app is not free, but a free trial is available.

The app can help you to export any conversation from your Slack workspace, including direct messages between you and an app. For example, if I need to export the conversation between me and Jira Cloud app, I just need to select the conversation and export it:[image]

Please also note, the app will automatically create an access token for you. By default, Primary Owner, Owners, Admins and Full Members are allowed to install any applications for Slack (and create access tokens). However, a workspace Admin or Owner may limit installations to pre-approved apps - in this case you will not be able to use the app as it will not be possible to install it.

Comment: Thanks, DenisL. I've attempted to install the app many times. Each time I encountered an error called "An error occurred while trying to rename a file in the destination directory: MoveFile failed; code 5.". And there are three options: 1) Try again; 2) Skip this file (not recommended) 3) Cancel installation. None of the options make the installation successful. What can I do now?

Comment: @JimmyZhao Thank you for your response. Any chance the .exe file is removed by any security app installed on your machine? I'm asking because we recently experienced the false detection with the AVG security which blocked our application for unknown reason (though virustotal.com show 0 detections of 68 AV-engines for our app: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5b8a7c29a10cf9cd98ef964d077812e84c6c06e37c3ab0851d10538cf3146176?nocache=1)

Comment: Just a quick update - we're not aware of any known false positives at this moment. If you experience any of them, please let me know, I'd be happy to help!